# I need a Toolbar that can dynamically add icons, and have them at certain positions

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-toolbar

I've run into a very peculiar problem with Toolbars. The way my team currently uses the Toolbar is via a wrapper class, let's call it `WrapToolbar`.

So `WrapToolbar` will internally setup a `Toolbar`, and exposes some common `Toolbar` functions. Things like `setTitle`, `getTitle`, etc are available.

This `WrapToolbar` also sets up a default icon. This way all usages of the `WrapToolbar` will have this icon available for the screens that need it.

The problem with this approach is that for screens that require additional icons, have to add them via a Menu XML and the `onCreateOptionsMenu` function.

When we do that, the default icon setup with `WrapToolbar` gets pushed to the left, and the new icons from the Menu XML get added at the end.

This has worked fine for us until recently when requirements changed, and now are asking for the default icon to be at the end all the time.

I'm currently wrestling with the idea of doing a custom wrapper around Toolbar that exposes the ability to add icons, get the title, set the title, etc. This way we can put the icons in any order, and have ultimate flexibility in how our Toolbar looks.

I'm looking for some guidance on what that might look like. I also want to get some feedback on whether my initial idea to solve for this is flawed in some way I haven't foreseen.

Comment: How exactly is the default icon set?

Comment: The icon is part of the Toolbar layout that gets inflated. So the `WrapToolbar` class has a `Toolbar` in it that has this layout inflated with the default icon.

Answer (score 1):

Menus have a built in ordering based on the `android:menuCategory` [attribute](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource) - you can use `android:menuCategory="secondary"` to push a menu item (like your default icon) to the end of the list - all MenuItems without a `menuCategory` will appear to the left of it.

Comment: This would solve the problem for me if I was using traditional menu XML's or MenuItem's for the default icon in my `WrapToolbar` class.

Comment: So why aren't you using a menu item for the default icon? You can use an [`ActionProvider`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/view/ActionProvider.html) for custom layouts / handling of clicks.

Comment: I haven't heard of `ActionProvider`, so thank you for sharing that. As for why we're not using a menu item for the default icon, it's because we want to easily share a Toolbar to all screens that have the default icon already set.

Then the Activity/Fragment can add more menu items to that Toolbar as needed.

Comment: I'm not sure why that would mean you couldn't have your `WrapToolbar` call `inflateMenu()` on itself in its constructor to add the default icon menu item.

Comment: Yeah, that's true. I'm going to give this a try, and report back. It sounds like a better solution than trying to fight the existing Menu system.